# Why is .getJSON function returning MIME type error from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have been trying to call from the [Forismatic API](http://forismatic.com/en/api/), but it is returning a MIME type error when I send it.

**JQuery Request:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#quote-button").on("click", function(){
       $.getJSON("https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en", function(json) {
  $(".quote-text").html(JSON.stringify(quoteText));
});

  });
 });
```

**Error Message**

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en&jsonp=jQuery32104928506782842177_1494780473751&_=1494780473752'
>   because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and
>   strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I have looked at adding `callback=?` and changing to `https` instead of `http`, but they haven't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per API documentation you need to set format to `"jsonp"` and set a `jsonp` param:

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?", function(json) {
  console.log(json)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```